# Flutter json object - type _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not subtype of type List<dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to set up an api connection to list wordpress users.

While making the same code in other APIs, it does not work on this json. I've read a lot about json object but I couldn't solve it.

The last error I got:

> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

When I set the model for name and id only, it works fine, but when I want to include fields such as acf, it always crashes into authorSnapshot.hasError.

Lists

```
List<dynamic> Akademisyens = [];
Future<List<dynamic>> _futureAkademisyens;
```

This is the JSON structure

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "",
    "url": "",
    "description": "",
    "link": "https://www..com/yazar/",
    "slug": "",
    "avatar_urls": {
      "24": "https://www..com/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatars/wp-user-avatars/assets/images/mystery.jpg",
      "48": "https://www..com/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatars/wp-user-avatars/assets/images/mystery.jpg",
      "96": "https://www..com/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatars/wp-user-avatars/assets/images/mystery.jpg"
    },
    "meta": [
      
    ],
    "acf": {
      "unvan": "",
      "universite": "",
      "calisma_alanlari": "",
      "profil_sayfasi_yazar_bilgileri": ""
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://www..com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/41"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://www..com/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "",
    "url": "https://www..com",
    "description": "",
    "link": "https://www..com/yazar/",
    "slug": "",
    "avatar_urls": {
      "24": "https://www..com/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatars/wp-user-avatars/assets/images/mystery.jpg",
      "48": "https://www..com/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatars/wp-user-avatars/assets/images/mystery.jpg",
      "96": "https://www..com/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatars/wp-user-avatars/assets/images/mystery.jpg"
    },
    "meta": [
      
    ],
    "acf": {
      "unvan": "Editör",
      "universite": ",
      "calisma_alanlari": "",
      "profil_sayfasi_yazar_bilgileri": ""
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://www..com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/10"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://www..com/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

My Model, I created with https://app.quicktype.io/:

```
import 'dart:convert';

AuthorList AuthorListFromJson(String str) => AuthorList.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String AuthorListToJson(AuthorList data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class AuthorList {
  AuthorList({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.url,
    this.description,
    this.link,
    this.slug,
    this.avatarUrls,
    this.meta,
    this.acf,
    this.links,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String url;
  String description;
  String link;
  String slug;
  Map<String, String> avatarUrls;
  List<dynamic> meta;
  Acf acf;
  Links links;

  factory AuthorList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AuthorList(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    url: json["url"],
    description: json["description"],
    link: json["link"],
    slug: json["slug"],
    avatarUrls: Map.from(json["avatar_urls"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, String>(k, v)),
    meta: List<dynamic>.from(json["meta"].map((x) => x)),
    acf: Acf.fromJson(json["acf"]),
    links: Links.fromJson(json["_links"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "url": url,
    "description": description,
    "link": link,
    "slug": slug,
    "avatar_urls": Map.from(avatarUrls).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
    "meta": List<dynamic>.from(meta.map((x) => x)),
    "acf": acf.toJson(),
    "_links": links.toJson(),
  };
}

class Acf {
  Acf({
    this.unvan,
    this.universite,
    this.calismaAlanlari,
    this.profilSayfasiYazarBilgileri,
  });

  String unvan;
  String universite;
  String calismaAlanlari;
  String profilSayfasiYazarBilgileri;

  factory Acf.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Acf(
    unvan: json["unvan"],
    universite: json["universite"],
    calismaAlanlari: json["calisma_alanlari"],
    profilSayfasiYazarBilgileri: json["profil_sayfasi_yazar_bilgileri"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "unvan": unvan,
    "universite": universite,
    "calisma_alanlari": calismaAlanlari,
    "profil_sayfasi_yazar_bilgileri": profilSayfasiYazarBilgileri,
  };
}

class Links {
  Links({
    this.self,
    this.collection,
  });

  List<Collection> self;
  List<Collection> collection;

  factory Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Links(
    self: List<Collection>.from(json["self"].map((x) => Collection.fromJson(x))),
    collection: List<Collection>.from(json["collection"].map((x) => Collection.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "self": List<dynamic>.from(self.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "collection": List<dynamic>.from(collection.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Collection {
  Collection({
    this.href,
  });

  String href;

  factory Collection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Collection(
    href: json["href"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "href": href,
  };
}
```

lastly my widget

```
  Widget getAkademisyensList(Future<List<dynamic>> Akademisyens) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: Akademisyens,
      builder: (context, authorSnapshot) {
        if (authorSnapshot.hasData) {
          if (authorSnapshot.data.length == 0) return Container();
          return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: authorSnapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                AuthorList author = authorSnapshot.data[index];

                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 16, 8),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              title: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {

                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  "${author.id}",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                  );

                return Container();
              });
        } else if (authorSnapshot.hasError) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 60, 0, 0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/no-internet.png",
                  width: 250,
                ),
                Text(
                  Conttext,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "ProductSans",
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  label: Text("Yeniden Yükle"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _futureAkademisyens = fetchAkademisyens();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Loading(
                indicator: BallBeatIndicator(),
                size: 60.0,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor));
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: In your json `"universite": ",` is missing a quotation mark?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is given by the fact that you don't initialize AuthorList  in the right way
Instead of doing this:

```
AuthorList author = authorSnapshot.data[index];
```

You should try to do this:

- Add something like this to the top of the model, before the definition of the class

```
List<AuthorList > authorListFromJson(String str) =>
    (List<AuthorList>.from(
        jsonDecode(str).map((x) => AuthorList.fromJson(x))));
```

- parse the json as a list of authorlist

```
List<AuthorList> authorList = authorListFromJson(authorSnapshot.data);
```